# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: orienit.hadoop.training.sed

Tags: java, hadoop, noclassdeffounderror

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: orienit.hadoop.training.sed
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)
```

running this in ubuntu......

in terminal my cmd is :hadoop jar /home/hadoop/work/testhadoop.jar orienit.hadoop.training.sed /words /sed

Comment: Does testhadoop.jar contain this compiled class?

Answer (score 0):

command should be like this:

`hadoop jar /home/hadoop/work/testhadoop.jar orienit.hadoop.training.sed.SedJob /words /sed`

your are missing the ClassName after the package